# Specified cast is not valid WPF, IValueCOnverter, C# - object to double

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I am trying to set up an IValueConverter in WPF, C#. The purpose of this converter is to take the value that is passed in and divide by 100 so that we can get a double. I don't see any error's in then code before launching, but when I go to test it, i get the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Here is the code for the converter:

```
public class DecimalPlace : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {           
            return System.Convert.ToDouble(value) / 100.00;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }      
    }
```

- Value = 5
- targetType = {Name = "String" FullName = "System.String"}

I am unsure as to why I am unable to cast value as a double to do the required math

This is where I am calling it:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="2*" Binding="{Binding intPrice, Converter={StaticResource DecimalPlace}, StringFormat='{}{0:C0}'}"/>
```

Comment: Is it trying to convert like .05 to an integer?

Comment: Tbh, I haven&#39;t even got to that part yet. In theory, that&#39;s what the code would do and break horribly. My issue is with converting value(5) to a double and then divide by 100 to get 0.05

Comment: Your functions are returning `object`. You need to return `Double` and `Int32` for the casts to be valid in your `return` statements.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception? what is the targetType? What does the binding look like?

Comment: Ah ya that's it return double

Comment: It's throwing the error on the return statement

Comment: Hmm, that might not be it, I can't recreate it. Sorry

Comment: No, they must return object because that is IConvertible interface.

Comment: Which return statement? There are two. What is the type of value? Please give the full exception (including stacktrace)

Comment: The first one where I am trying to divide by 100. The value is 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that targetType is `string` and the exception isn't actually occurring in your code (you neglected to post the stacktrace). It's being bound to a `DataGridTextColumn` which needs a string. So your converter *must* return a string. Normally WPF automatically handles converting between types like `string` and `double` in a binding when going from source to target and vice verse, but if you specify your own converter, you must make sure to provide exactly the correct return type.

The simple fix is:

```
public class DecimalPlace : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {           
        return (System.Convert.ToDouble(value) / 100.00).ToString();
    }    
}
```

But if you want a more generic useful converter, you'll need to check `targetType` and convert to the correct type (you can possibly use `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter`

Answer (score 0):

Please include the Xaml where you use this converter. My guess is that you use the empty string initially in the textbox. Try to apply a fallback value to 0. You should check in the converter code that your input value can in fact be parsed to a number, using for example double.TryParse !

```
<TextBox Text=“{Binding MyNumberInViewModel, Mode=Twoway, Fallbackvalue=‘0’}” />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant, more resilient to missing validation.

```
public class DecimalPlace : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {           
        double parsed=0;
        if (!double.TryParse(out parsed))
         return parsed;

         return (parsed) / 100.00;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
           double parsed=0;
        if (!double.TryParse(out parsed))
         return parsed;

        return System.Convert.ToInt32(parsed) * 100;
    }      
}
```